# R: How can I convert my dataframe using two columns to create a consecutive row

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to transform my data frame so that two columns (MinYear, MaxYear) merge together into a new column (Year) that consists of consecutive sequences limited by MinYear and MaxYear.

My data frame looks like this:

| Value | MinYear | MaxYear |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5,2 | 1997 | 2000 |
| 3,3 | 1996 | 2000 |

I want to get my data frame like this:

| Value | Year |
| --- | --- |
| 5,2 | 2000 |
| 5,2 | 1999 |
| 5,2 | 1998 |
| 5,2 | 1997 |
| 3,3 | 2000 |
| 3,3 | 1999 |
| 3,3 | 1998 |
| 3,3 | 1997 |
| 3,3 | 1996 |
| 3,3 | 1995 |

Do you have any glues on how to solve that issue?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by `Value` and use `dplyr::summarize`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Value) %>% 
  summarize(Year = MaxYear:MinYear, .groups="drop")
```

Output:

```
  Value  Year
  <chr> <int>
1 3,3    2000
2 3,3    1999
3 3,3    1998
4 3,3    1997
5 3,3    1996
6 5,2    2000
7 5,2    1999
8 5,2    1998
9 5,2    1997
```

If `Value` is not unique, you can use `rowwise()` to ensure that this is executed separately for each row of the original frame:

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  summarize(Value = Value, Year = MaxYear:MinYear)
```

Input:

```
df = structure(list(Value = c("5,2", "3,3"), MinYear = 1997:1996, 
    MaxYear = c(2000L, 2000L)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use `map2` from `purrr`. For each row, it will create a `seq`uence of `Year`s based on `MaxYear` and `MinYear`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  transmute(Value, Year = map2(MaxYear, MinYear, seq)) %>%
  unnest(cols = Year)
```

**Output**

```
  Value  Year
  <chr> <int>
1 5,2    2000
2 5,2    1999
3 5,2    1998
4 5,2    1997
5 3,3    2000
6 3,3    1999
7 3,3    1998
8 3,3    1997
9 3,3    1996
```